# The strpos is fails to return the postion of a string in another string

Tags: php, strpos

strpos is failing and prints description inside the loop.What might be the reason for this.For some of the string it is working.But here it is not working.

```
$text ="<ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped with XF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li></ul>";

$description = "The adoption of the dual CPU and improved performance has doubled the processing speed when compared with the previous generation processor*, the start-up time has also improved to only approx. 0.5 sec.** Working in tandem with the high-speed signal readout of the X-Trans CMOS II sensor, the processor reduces the shooting interval to 0.5 sec.*** and shutter time lag to 0.05 sec<br /><ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped with XF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li>
</ul>";


if($text!="" && strpos($description,$text) === false)
                    {
                        echo $description;exit;

                    }
```

Comment: Do you take spaces, line breaks into account? Looks like $text is actually _not_ a substring of description..

Comment: $text and `<ul>` part in description is not the same. You have bunch of spaces between `<ul>` and first `<li>`.

Comment: I have removed spaces.Also not working

Comment: Not the same again. In $text you have `withXF27mmF2.8` and in $description it's `with XF27mmF2.8`. Note the space between.

Comment: sorry while editing second time it is combined(withXF27mmF2.8).Removed space also no use

Comment: You have break line at the end of your description between `</li>` and `</ul>`. This can go on till infinity. Your code is OK, just your strings simply do not match. Here is the [proof](http://codepad.org/UVwYGU9E)

Comment: ok.Is there any other solution for this other than strpos

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove extra spaces and same as `$text` string in `$description`  try

```
$text ="<ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped withXF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li></ul>";
$description = "The adoption of the dual CPU and improved performance has doubled the processing speed when compared with the previous generation processor*, the start-up time has also improved to only approx. 0.5 sec.** Working in tandem with the high-speed signal readout of the X-Trans CMOS II sensor, the processor reduces the shooting interval to 0.5 sec.*** and shutter time lag to 0.05 sec<br /><ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped withXF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li></ul>";
if($text!="" && strpos($description,$text) === false) {
    echo $description;exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have removed.I have updated my code above.Even thought it is not working

Comment: try my updated answer you still going wrong i have pasted your text in desc and good goin

Comment: its working.I am getting these values from xml.But while parsing it is failing.What might be the reason?

Comment: reason is both are not same so use concat string without space also show your code

Answer (score 0):

that's because the new line before the last 
so it's not identical

try remove the new lines

```
$text ="<ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped with XF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li></ul>";

$description = "The adoption of the dual CPU and improved performance has doubled the processing speed when compared with the previous generation processor*, the start-up time has also improved to only approx. 0.5 sec.** Working in tandem with the high-speed signal readout of the X-Trans CMOS II sensor, the processor reduces the shooting interval to 0.5 sec.*** and shutter time lag to 0.05 sec<br /><ul><li>*Compared with the EXR Processor Pro.</li><li>**Equipped with XF27mmF2.8 in High Performance mode.</li><li>***MF mode.</li>
</ul>";
// remove the new lines
$text = preg_replace('/\n/', '', $text) ;
$description = preg_replace('/\n/', '', $description) ;

if($text!="" && strpos($description,$text) === false)
{
    echo $description;exit;
}
```

Comment: i have tested the code above . what is the problem ?

Comment: it is entering inside the loop and printing description i.e the even if we use the preg_replace,here the strpos not working